# Create MULTIPLE ROWS TO COMMA Separator

Tags: sql-server

Sample data:

**Table A**:

```
  BillID    ID_B
  --------------
  122        1
  122        2
```

**Table B**:

```
  ID_B     Name         
  ------------------
    1      Jakarta              
    2      Malang
    3      Wonosobo
```

Expected result:

```
 BillID     Name
 ------           -----------------
  122         Jakarta, Malang
```

TableA.ID_B = TableB.ID_B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT BillID,STUFF((SELECT ',' + Name
FROM TABLEB AS T2
WHERE T2.ID_B = T1.ID_B
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1) AS Name FROM TABLEA AS T1
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT STUFF((
    SELECT
        ',' + [Name]
    FROM
        B AS B
    WHERE
        B.ID_B IN (SELECT ID_B FROM A)
    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS [Name]
```